# Loading associated models in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have related models `Track` and `Milestone` as follows:

```
App.Track = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  milestones: DS.hasMany('milestone', {
    async: true
  })
});

App.Milestone = DS.Model.extend({
  track: DS.belongsTo('track'),
  title: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr(),
});
```

Now, I would like to lazy load the milestones for a track. I believe the default expectation of Ember data is that the response returned by the endpoint returning track also contains an array of milestone ids, ie. something like :

`GET: /tracks/1`

```
{
    "title": "My track",
    "description": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "milestones": [1,2,3]
}
```

My backend is a relational database, and I would like to avoid joining tracks and milestones unless necessary.

So my expectation would be that even if the response returned by tracks endpoint contains no milestones array, the following should make a request to `/tracks/1/milestones` and associate the obtained milestones with the relevant track.

```
 this.store.find('track', params.track_id).then(function(track) {
  return track.get('milestones').then(function(milestones) {
    return console.log(milestones);
  });
});
```

The above snippet is inside a Route#model method.

Is it feasible to accomplish this using Ember Data ? If not then can I use some other persistence library for Ember ? Please don't suggest using `$.ajax` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are returning your JSON for tracks, Ember-Data will use the [findMany](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findMany) method and request `GET: /milestones?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3`.

If you want Ember Data to instead request `GET: /tracks/1/milestones` (using the [findHasMany](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany) method), you'll need to format your tracks JSON with a `links` property like so

```
{
    "title": "My track",
    "description": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "links": { "milestones": "/tracks/1/milestones" }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ember-Data's REST Adapter roughly follows the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org) standard, both URL and ID based. It sounds like what you want is URL based loading. Take a look at an example in the [REST Adapter documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany). This will lazy-load both the records and the IDs for the records.